# How to Manually Xen bridging setup on OpenSUSE for two DomU

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, xen, opensuse

I've been having problems with Xen networking on OpenSUSE, specifically with getting Dom0 opening a TCP connection to the DomU.  Other machines on the network can open TCP connections to all 3, so I'm hoping a manual network configuration will let me resolve the Dom0 -> DomU issue.

So I need help to manually configure my Dom0 network, bridge, and 2 VIF interfaces in OpenSUSE.  Ideally I'll have 3 mac addresses, two randomly generated for each VIF and one for the Dom0.  This way my internal DHCP/DNS server can assign each a IP and all machines on the lan can connect to all 3 servers.  All 3 machines should be on the same internal network with everything else (no VLAN or NAT).  NOTE: You can assume this is a **static** network setup, I'm just using DHCP with static MACs for convenience, but I expect the IPs of Dom0, and DomUs to be fixed.

**1)** How do I configure this network start to finish in YaST?

**or**

**2)** Please provide sample /etc/sysconfig/network scripts, and any other config file scripts to set this up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I create the bridges manually using the ifcfg- files in /etc/sysconfig/network.  I have a bridge attached to eth0 that gets passed to domUs.  Below are my ifcfg-eth0 and ifcfg-br5000 files.  It's slightly different if you need to bridge a VLAN, but since you don't indicate as much, I assume that's not needed.

eth0:

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
#IPADDR='172.16.30.221/24'
IPADDR='0.0.0.0/24'
BROADCAST='172.16.30.255'
MTU=9000''
STARTMODE='onboot'
NAME='Ethernet Network Card'
```

br5000:

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
BRIDGE='yes'
BRIDGE_FORWARDDELAY='0'
BRIDGE_PORTS='eth0'
BRIDGE_STP='off'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='172.16.30.221/24'
MTU='9000'
NAME=''
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
USERCONTROL='no'
```

Comment: That's half of it.  How would I manually create the two VIF interfaces so they can use the bridge, giving them 2 different MAC and IP addresses.

Comment: You don't create the vifs, Xen does when it creates the VM.  In your domU config file, you would set a line like: vif = [ 'mac=00:16:3e:42:49:01, bridge=br5000']  Then, in the domU, you can get an IP via DHCP or set it statically.  Or set it in the domU configuration file.

Comment: Yeah, that much works right... And I can RDesktop from a laptop to the DomU.  But RDesktop form Dom0 to DomU doesn't work.

So I was thinking if I could set up the VIF in SuSE, then I can just tell XEN use this VIF

Comment: What versions of:  OpenSuSE dom0, Xen, domU ?

Comment: OpenSUSE 11.4 , kernel is 2.6.37.6-0.9, xen is `/boot/xen-4.0.2_52`. I tried your scripts, commented out the vif-script and network-script. My VM vif line is. `vif=[ 'mac=08:00:27:11:D9:B1,ip=192.168.1.211,type=ioemu,bridge=br0' ]`.  Still, it's the same error where dom0 can ping, but not open a TCP connection to DomU.  I asked this on Xen-Users too.

Answer (score 0):

I am more familiar with XEN under SLES, but I think OpenSuSE will be similar.

If bridging is available via `yast network` try that one (works on SLES11, not on SLES10).

If bridging is not available via yast look into **/etc/xen/scripts**. There you should find a script called `network-bridge`. Use that wrapper-script to move your Dom0-Interface onto the bridge (look into the head of the script for parameters).

I found it to be necessary to put a configuration **/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-$BRIDGE** with **startmode manual** so that the bridge will be up after the network-bridge-script runs.

The basic trick of the wrapper-script is to move the MAC (and IP) from the physical interface to the bridge-device. The original interface will be added to the bridge and renamed to PETH - serving as "uplink" to the network.